# Django Graphene, Passing JSON or dict data as input for Mutation

Tags: django, graphene-python, graphiql

I have the following situation: I have a User, each user has a Inventory. I'm struggling to declare the user's inventory in the Mutation "CreateUser". Here is the following mutation for creating the user:

```
mutation Create{
  addUser(UserData:{name:"Shibunika",age:21}
}
```

I'm trying to declare the user's inventory in this mutation, I expected something like

```
mutation Create{
  addUser(UserData:{name:"Shibunika",age:21,inventory:{'item1':45,'item2':25}
}s
```

these number are the quantity of each item.
How do I define these inputs in graphene?
Would you gently show me a schema for this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can create a custom object type to represent a key value pair, and then have a list of these in your user schema.

```
class InventoryKeyValueType(graphene.InputObjectType):
    name = graphene.String(required=True)
    int_value = graphene.Int(required=True)

class AddUser(graphene.Mutation):
    user = graphene.Field(lambda: UserType)
    ok = graphene.Boolean()

    class Arguments:
        # User Fields
        name = graphene.String()
        ....

        inventory = graphene.List(InventoryKeyValueType)
```

The syntax is a bit clunky but workable:

`mutation { addUser(name:"Shibunika",  age:21, inventory:[ {name: "item1", intValue: 45}, {name: "item2", intValue:25}]){ok}`

**Other Input Types**

This approach could easily be extended for other input types beyond integers, for example replacing

```
    int_value = graphene.Int(...
```

with

```
    str_value = graphene.String(...
```

Comment: excellent answer, thanks – now for people who are as dense as me, please note how the type that `inventory` is expecting is derived from `InputObjectType` and NOT `ObjectType`....

Comment: `inventory` requires a `List` of `InventoryKeyValueType` objects, which inherit from `InputObjectType`

Answer (score 3):

Graphene provides a `GenericScalar` type. You can use it to input/output generic types like `int`, `str`, `dict`, `list`, etc.

```
from graphene import InputObjectType, Mutation, String, Int
from graphene.types.generic import GenericScalar

class UserInput(InputObjectType):
    name = String()
    age = Int()
    inventory = GenericScalar()

class addUser(Mutation):
    class Arguments:
        user_data = UserInput()

    def mutate(root, info, user_data):
        # do something with user_data
```

Your input would look like

```
mutation Create {
  addUser (
    userData: {
      name: "Shibunika"
      age: 21
      inventory: {
        item1: 45,
        item2: 25
      }
    }
  )
}
```

Note that `inventory` can accept any generic input, so make sure to validate it.

Also, when using a `GenericScalar` field for output (query), you won't be able to query its subfields e.g. `item1`, `item2`. But you can write a resolver for that field to make sure only specific subfields are returned.

[Here](https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene/issues/384) is the link to the corresponding GitHub issue.

In your case, `inventory` field has a well-defined structure, so Mark Chackerian's solution fits better.