# Can we write a resolver for a python dictionary in graphql?

Tags: python, graphql, graphene-python, graphene-django

I'm trying to write a resolver in python graphql for the non-table data. For example, my dictionary is as follows:

```
api_list={1:"API 1", 2:"API 2"}
```

I want the graphql result as

```
[
   {
      "name":"API 01"
   },
   {
      "name":"API 02"
   }
]
```

I tried using the Query as

```
class Query(ObjectType):
  apis = List()
  def resolve_apis(self, info, api_list):
      results = []
      for key, value in apis_list.items():
          api = {}
          api[key] = value
          results.append(api)
      return results
```

But getting an error saying that: a model type is not defined. Can we write a resolver for returning dictionary elements without putting them in a Django table in real?

```
__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'of_type'
```

Comment: Do you want to get the query result of api_list={1:"API 1", 2:"API 2"} as [
   {
      "name":"API 01"
   },
   {
      "name":"API 02"
   }
] ? or are you expecting api_list as query param and returning the same in [
   {
      "name":"API 01"
   },
   {
      "name":"API 02"
   }
]  format ?

Comment: You're on the right track, but you need to provide arguments to `List` -- see https://docs.graphene-python.org/en/latest/types/list-and-nonnull/ or better yet, see this related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51224477/django-graphene-passing-json-or-dict-data-as-input-for-mutation/51269035 which shows how to a dictionary for mutation.

Comment: Thanks, @MarkChackerian, the second link clearly explained a solution.